# How can I create a dotted design surface like VB6 forms?

Tags: wpf

What control do can I use to simulate VB6's dotted design surface?

I want to create room maps and I want the user to be able to align the items while dragging.

Comment: Are you asking how to make dots or how to snap-drag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to make the dots every ten pixels using a `DrawingBrush`:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,10,10" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,10,10"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I believe the easiest way to do it would be to use an array, such as is mentioned here:   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/Vsexpressvb/thread/5626ef50-c2df-4e59-a8e9-3ae6eaa98ce9

and just make the background of your form a plain grey box, with darker dots that align to the points in the array